# Why do these NEF files appear corrupt in Adobe Bridge but fixed by opening in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, adobe, data-corruption

I recently took some images of a girls soccer team.  Upon opening the images in Adobe bridge, about 12 of 250 images had missing data.  The "bad" images used different lenses, shutter speeds (from 1/8000 - 1/200), apertures, ISO and flash/no flash.

example: http://www.frozenpixelstudios.com/p342759622/ead12d15#h1168e8d1

At first, I thought I had a shutter issue, but I would think that there would be some data in the "black area".  For the heck of it, I opened one of the images in Photoshop, and the issue went away.

example: http://www.frozenpixelstudios.com/p342759622/ead12d15#had12d15

My second guess was that this is just an error while writing the embedded jpg to the NEF file?  However, these errors didn't show up on the camera's LCD.  Also, after opening the file, the issue goes away in bridge -- its almost as if it is being "fixed", but NEF files can't be edited.  When I copy the NEF to a new location, the image is still "repaired".

Any ideas what is happening, or what could cause this?

(relevant camera data is in exif data for the second picture, approximately 70,000 clicks on a D3 body)

Comment: I suspect a computer hardware problem of some sort. Do you still have the untouched originals on a memory card?

Comment: A couple of more questions... What version of Photoshop/Bridge are you using? Is it up to date? What happens when one of these is opened in Capture NX?

Comment: The untouched originals are no longer on a memory card, but I did catch this early enough to copy them a second and third time - same result.

Comment: Im using CS4 and it is up to date.  Again, I'm at 70,000 clicks on this body and never seen this before.  Im anxious to get out and shoot again.  I tried some tests in the basement and couldn't reproduce it.

Comment: @matt - I didn't mind the title edit, but couldn't resist the rollback badge :-)

Comment: @Jess -- no problem. :) Welcome to the community here! I do suggest a more meaningful title, though. It'll be more likely to bring in someone who knows what's going on, and more helpful to people who have a similar issue. Same with the "data-corruption" tag.

Comment: When you copied them a second and third time, is the same result that they're corrupted in Bridge and then okay, or is it that they always seem fine now?

Comment: I assume the problem is with thumbnail images in the cache, not a problem with the NEF file. First thing I'd do is adjust the thumbnail size in Bridge and see if it recreates the thumbnails. If not, then clear the cache and restart bridge and see if the problem goes away.  And as Joanne C suggested, try Capture NX or View NX to see if it's an Adobe related issue, or actually something wrong with your NEF files.  I'll bet it's the Adobe cache.

Comment: I was out again this weekend and ran another 900+ images and didn't have an issue. Ian's suggestion of clearing the cache led me to what I think caused the issue. Most of the time (99%) I pull the card from the camera and copy the images from a memory card reader. For the time in question, I had Bridge open and was pulling the images through the camera body. I'm guessing that as Bridge was reading the images, it hiccuped and caused some incomplete reads and sent them to cache. Maybe even when I recopied them and moved them, the cache is stored by image name and never really re-read the actual

Comment: Had same problem - Bad ram - if using windows, run memory checker. replaced flaky ram - no more problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jess,

I'll ask "the stupid question" first:  Have you tried clearing the cache in Bridge?

With that out of the way:  Have you tried to preview the images in a file manager other than Bridge?

Iain

Comment: (OK these are essentially the same question - what I'm getting at is that I think Bridge builds its own previews rather than using those built into the image)

Comment: I have tried clearing the cache for images on a one-by-one basis.  That didn't work.

Comment: Hmmm... sorry for the hiatus, coursework and exams for my MSc and real life happened to intervene!

Have you tried another file manager to view the images?